# Finding equivalence classes of gcd

Tags: equivalence-relations, gcd-and-lcm

Let $A=\{1,2,3..n\}$, $(n>10)$ following the rule:

for $x,y \in A$, we would say that $x\sim y,$ $\space$ **iff** $gcd(x,n) = gcd(y,n)$.

find the equivalence classes in case $n=6p$ while $p$ is prime number and $4 \lt p$ .

I'm kind of new to this, but if I select $[1]$ as the first class, doesn't it suppose to have all the numbers til $n$ because $gcd(x,1)=1$ for any intiger $x$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $n = 6p$ for $p$ a prime, two numbers $x,y$ are in the same equivalence class if $\gcd(x,6p) = \gcd(y,6p)$. So the equivalence classes correspond to the factors of $6p$. Since $p>4$, you will find that the equivalence classes are $\bar 1$, $\bar 2$, $\bar 3$, $\bar 6$, $\bar p$, $\overline{2p}$, $\overline{3p}$, and $\overline{6p}$.

---

To address your second question, if you select $\bar 1$ as the first class, you are looking at the set of all numbers $y$ such that $\gcd(y,n) = \gcd(1,n) = 1$. Take, for example, $n = 4$. Then the equivalence class $\bar 1 = \{1,3\}$.

Comment: Can you please explain how did you get to the answers of  $\bar 1$, $\bar 2$, $\bar 3$, $\bar 6$, $\bar p$, $\overline{2p}$, $\overline{3p}$, and $\overline{6p}$ ?

Comment: If $p=11$, what is the equivalence class of $7$?

Comment: @OfekPintok The only possible values for $\gcd(x,6p)$ are $1,2,3,6,p,2p,3p,6p$. Each one of these must be in its own equivalence class.

Comment: @amrsa Is that question for me? $7 \in \bar 1$.

Comment: Yes, bames it was for you, but you're right, of course. Nevermind.

Comment: I read the question as if it were $x \sim y$ iff $x = y \mod p$. :(